# How to store HTML content efficiently in MSSQL database

Tags: html, sql-server

im looking for a method to store large amounts of HTML into a database table or whether i should just store it in S3 as individual files.

My requirement is to process multiple page documents, which could be MS Word or PDF but have users enter their content into a web based editor.

Upon saving their data, it will be HTML or a JSON string based on the editor i choose to use. This content could have a variety of html formatting applied and will be able to be viewed by browser and or exported to PDF or docx files if required.

Im currently looking at storing it directly into my MSSQL database, but curious to know if it should be converted to Bas64 or if i should just leave it as HTML.

Is there a better solution i should be looking at, any ideas greatly appreciated

Comment: If you're storing HTML, and it's **well** formed, you can store it in an `xml` column, though HTML tends to rarely be so well formatted that it will mean the requirements of the `xml` data type. JSON data is supported in recent versions of SQL Server, and should be stored using an `nvarchar(MAX)`; which you could also use to store HTML as well. As for whether to store in files or SQL Server, that's quite the open question, if I am honest, as some what off topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: You can store well-formed **X**HTML in SQL Server's XML data type. HTML that uses null tags like <br>, <hr> and <img> cannot be stored in XML variables and columns, though, and attempting to do so will result in `end tag does not match start tag` XML parsing errors.

Comment: Given the different formats, I'd store them in a VARCHAR(MAX) ( or NVARCHAR(MAX) depending on your need ). As for encoding to Base64, unless there's a specific reason that seems unnecessary to me.